# How to add bullet points to new lines in ACF Text Area field

Tags: wordpress, echo, advanced-custom-fields, explode, implode

I have an ACF Text Area field (2 actually) on my clients Wordpress site that will contain a list. The client wants this to output as bullet points on the front end.

I am relatively new to JS so trying to work out how exactly to do this!

I found this - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-format_value/ - from ACF in terms of adding formatting to certain fields, so have worked out how to add the code to the fields! However, I am struggling to figure out what coding to put in the middle to get each `<br>` to add a new `<li>` instead...

```
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    $my_acf_format_value = explode("\n", $value);
    
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $value) . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_included', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_to_bring', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```

This is being implemented on the fields, but isn't outputting any of the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

This would work, you need to use return $value instead of echo

```
    function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    
         $items_as_array = explode("\n", $value);
    
         $output = "<ul style='list-style-type: circle;'><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $items_as_array) . "</li></ul>";
    
         return $output;
     }
     
     
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_included', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_to_bring', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just making it a wysiwyg field and telling the client to put bullet points if they wanted it

Answer (score 1):

Despite the nice attempts it is never a good idea to output (`echo`) directly in the filter function. It will screw with the difference between `the_field()` and `get_field()`.

Instead, you'd like to do this

```php
$format_acf_bullet = function(
    string $value,
    int $post_id,
    array $form ):string {
    if( empty($value) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $lines = explode( "\n", $value );
    $result = "<ul>\n";
    $result .= "<li>".implode( "\n<li>", $lines );
    $result .= "</ul>\n";
    return $result;
};

add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_included', $format_acf_bullet, 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_included', $format_acf_bullet, 10, 3);
```

Tested with ACF 1.3.5 WP 6.0.2 PHP 8.1.5

(and yes the  `</li>` is optional)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style `list-style: circle;` to `ul`. check below code.

```
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    $my_acf_format_value = explode("\n", $value);
    
    echo '<ul style="list-style-type: circle;">';
    echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $my_acf_format_value) . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_included', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_to_bring', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the above code isn't actually outputting the data from within the text field. It was outputting, then I added this code (to try to output with the bullet points) and it stopped showing anything where this field shows.

I think that the code is maybe missing something or incorrect (I have jumbled it together from multiple sources), but I am not sure where to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

     $items_from_text_area = explode("\n", $value);

     $items_as_array = explode('\n', $items_from_text_area);

     $output = "<ul style='list-style-type: circle;'><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $items_as_array) . "</li></ul>";

     return $output;
 }

   add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_included', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
   add_filter('acf/format_value/name=averetourism_tour_to_bring', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```